# How to post an issue on GitHub with GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to post an issue on GitHub with the GitHub API.

I looked at the API documentation, 
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue
but I can't figure out where the account information should go in the request body.

How should I authenticate this request?

Comment: See https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see example of scripts posting issues in:

- "['mapserver-trac-importer](https://gist.github.com/tbonfort/2959820)" (authentication [`github_post`](https://gist.github.com/tbonfort/2959820#file-gistfile1-aw-L423-L431), with user/password)
- "[simple basic-auth node github api](https://gist.github.com/fat/3030931)" ([authentication here](https://gist.github.com/fat/3030931#file-github-js-L30-L37), with user/password)
- "[`.bashrc`](https://gist.github.com/cstrahan/b429ffc4c70bbb59d63f)" ([authentication in curl](https://gist.github.com/cstrahan/b429ffc4c70bbb59d63f#file-bashrc-L48-L52), with oauth)

As described in [API V3 authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), you can either user username/password, or an [oauth token](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/).

Note that if you have activated the 2FA (2 Form Authentication), you will *need* an oauth token.

I prefer oauth anyway, because you can revoke the token at any time (token that you can create just for this script), without having the hassle to change your password (which you could use in multiple other instances).